# UIImageView hugging & compression priority not working properly when new image is inserted

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, snapkit

I'm trying to make `view` like this:

[image]

Everything works fine, but when I put image from API to that `UIImageView`, this happens:
[image]
`UIImageView` is stretching even with some `Hugging Priority` and `Compression priority`

### Code for View:

```swift
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let contentView = UIView()

    lazy var posterImage = UIImageView().then {
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        $0.image = UIImage(named: "img_placeholder")    // placeholder image
        
        $0.backgroundColor = .orange
        $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    }
    
    lazy var titleLabel = UILabel().then {
        $0.textColor = .white
        $0.textAlignment = .left
        
        $0.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .medium)
        $0.numberOfLines = 0
        $0.minimumScaleFactor = 10
        
        $0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
    }
    
    lazy var taglineLabel = UILabel().then {
        $0.numberOfLines = 0
        $0.textColor = .lightGray
        $0.textAlignment = .left
        $0.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
    }
    
    lazy var runtimeIconLabel = IconLabel().then {
        $0.icon.image = UIImage(systemName: "clock")
    }
    
    lazy var ratingIconLabel = IconLabel().then {
        $0.icon.image = UIImage(systemName: "star.fill")
        $0.icon.tintColor = .orange
    }
    
    lazy var iconLabels = UIStackView().then {
        $0.addArrangedSubview(runtimeIconLabel)
        $0.addArrangedSubview(ratingIconLabel)
        
        $0.axis = .horizontal
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.alignment = .leading
        $0.spacing = 5
    }
    
    lazy var mainInfoLabelStack = UIStackView().then {
        $0.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        $0.addArrangedSubview(taglineLabel)
        $0.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
        $0.addArrangedSubview(iconLabels)
        
        $0.axis = .vertical
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.alignment = .leading
        $0.spacing = 5
    }
        
    lazy var mainInfoStackView = UIStackView().then {
        $0.addArrangedSubview(posterImage)
        $0.addArrangedSubview(mainInfoLabelStack)
        
        $0.axis = .horizontal
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.alignment = .fill
        $0.spacing = 10
        $0.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        $0.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.detailViewComponentInset

        posterImage.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        mainInfoLabelStack.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)

    }
```

### Adding Constraints:

```swift
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
        }

        contentView.addSubview(mainInfoStackView)

        mainInfoStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(self.view.snp.width).multipliedBy(0.45)
        }
```

**I want to remove unintended margin of `UIImageView`**

Comment: What is `.then`? I really like this notation.

Comment: https://github.com/devxoul/Then
It's syntactic sugar for swift initializers

Comment: Thank you! Nice. I've used the same dev's URLNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

You must set image contentMode to "scaleAspectFill" for the "posterImage" because of dimension:

```
lazy var posterImage = UIImageView().then {
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        $0.image = UIImage(named: "img_placeholder")    // placeholder image
        
        $0.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
```

remove the below code

```
$0.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

and set fix width and height constraint for the image

Comment: I tried your solution, but it just makes poster image bigger (seems like original size). Seems the width of UIImageView is `width` of **Original image**. Is there any idea about why this happens?

Comment: has your image view fixed width and height?
you must remove posterImage.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

A `UIImageView` has no intrinsic size, until an image has been set. At that point, if you haven't given constraint conditions to control it, UIKit will change its size based on the new image.

You probably want something like this:

```
posterImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.width.equalTo(posterImage.snp.height).multipliedBy(0.75)
}
```

to give the image view a 4:3 ratio.

Adjust that `.multipliedBy` value to suit your design.

---

**Edit**

Here's the result...

Initially, `posterImage` has a "placeholder" image:

[image]

then we set its image to [this one](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWMyYzFjYTYtNTRjYi00OGExLWE2YzgtOGRmYjAxZTU3NzBiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzQ0MzA0NTM@._V1_FMjpg_UX1000_.jpg):

[image]

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, constraints seems not working in my stack view

Comment: @DanChoi - see the **Edit** to my answer. Isn't that your goal?